# Outgoing payment print error -199 openPrinter

Tags: sapb1

When I updated my SAP database from MSSQL 2008 to MSSQL 2008 R2, Outgoing payment printing is making error (-199) openPrinter and exit the program.

The sample error

[image]

If anyone knows this error, please help.

Comment: Why are you using A) such an old version of SQL Server (they just released 2017!) and B) an old version of B1? It could be that the version of B1 you're using doesn't support the version of SQL server you're running.

Comment: Hi Phroureo,

When we upgraded the database from SQL 2008 to 2014 we had more errors, and when using 2008 R2 we had it successfully in migrating the database. But then after four months we encountered that error.

Comment: Sounds to me like the SQL upgrade isn't responsible for the issue, then, if it was working previously. I would suggest asking on the SCN--it's generally more suited for this type of question.